# To take input a sentence and check if it contains any word input by the user, also print the count

Tags: java

I am working on a program in java the output should be something like below :

```
Input the sentence
hello how how are you
enter code here

Input the word that has to be searched
how

Output : 
the string is present and the count of the string how is : 2

I have written a program but i am not able to count the search string can anyone please help me on this and below is the code
```

I think there is a problem with the looping as well i am able to find the string present in the sentence but not able to count.

```
        boolean contains = false;

        /*Inputting the sentence*/
        java.util.Scanner scn = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input the sentence");
        String s = scn.nextLine();
        String[] lstarr = s.split(" ");

        /*Inputting the string*/
        java.util.Scanner scn2 = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input the word to be searched");
        String s2 = scn.nextLine();
        String[] explst = s2.split(" ");

        /*searching the input word */
        if(s.contains(s2)){    
            contains = true;
            System.out.println("Input word is present : " + s2);
        }

        else{

            System.out.println("String " + s2 + "is not present");
        }

        ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

        Collections.addAll(lst, lstarr);

        for(String str : lst) {

            System.out.println(str + " " + Collections.frequency(lst, str));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     System.out.println("Input the sentence");
     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
     String input = s.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Input the word that has to be searched");
     String word = s.nextLine();

     String str = "";
     int occurance = 0;
     for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
         str += c;
         if(str.length() == word.length()) {
             if(str.equals(word)) {
                 occurance ++;
             }

             str = str.substring(1);
         }
     }

     if(occurance > 0)
         System.out.println("the string is present and the count of the given string is : " + occurance);
     else 
         System.out.println("The string is not present");
}
```

Comment: +1 for condition like you are searching for Ex- `gaga` in `gagaga` this will give `2` rather than `1` that is as expected.best way to search any `subString` inside a `String`.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians *"that is as expected"* - I've not read that any where in the requirements, and "gagaga" is a single word, not multiples. You seem to be making up requirements which don't exist

Comment: Yuo @MadProgrammer I am so much impressed with your your approach of coading,could I change my name to`SadProgrammer` :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I told in general this is a good way to search any subString inside a String,this is not specific to his requirment.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `Collections.addAll`:

This will give you the frequency of all the words in the input sentence.

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList(lstarr);
for(String str : input) {
    System.out.println(str + " " + Collections.frequency(input , str));
}
```

Of course, if you only want the frequency of the searched word, you need :

```
System.out.println(s2 + " " + Collections.frequency(input, s2));
```

Comment: No worries, didn't think that's what you meant ;)

Comment: `s2` can be combination of two string as well.your code will definitely fail when there is a combination of words.you cant store them in a `list/collection` of separate `String`.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians based on `Input the word that has to be searched` I assumed that we are searching for a single word.

Answer (score 1):

So, your basic problem revoles around the desire to convert an array (of `String`s) to a `List` of `String`s

You can add an array of values to a collection in at least three ways...

You could use `Arrays.asList`...

```
List<String> lst = Arrays.asList(lstarr);
```

which returns a non-mutable `List`, which would suit your needs, but you can also use...

```
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lstarr));
```

or

```
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.addAll(Arrays.asList(lstarr));
```

Which will give you a mutable list...

You can then check for the frequency of the work simply by using `Collections.frequency` directly...

```
System.out.println(s2 + " " + Collections.frequency(lst, s2));
```

## Multiple word search...(for some reason)

```
    String text = "how hello how how are you";
    String query = "how hello";

    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    List<String> wordsList = Arrays.asList(words);
    String[] matches = query.split(" ");
    for (String match : matches) {
        System.out.println(match + " occurs " + Collections.frequency(wordsList, match) + " times");
    }
```

Which, based on my input, outputs

```
how occurs 3 times
hello occurs 1 times
```

You could even use a regular expression...

```
for (String match : matches) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(match);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(match + " occurs " + count + " times");
}
```

You could even use a temporary list and simple remove all the occurrences of the given word from it and calculate the difference in size...

```
List<String> check = new ArrayList<>(25);
for (String match : matches) {
    check.addAll(wordsList);
    int startSize = check.size();
    check.removeAll(Arrays.asList(new String[]{match}));
    int endSize = check.size();
    System.out.println(match + " occurs " + (startSize - endSize) + " times");
    check.clear();
}
```

But I think that goes "way" beyond what is been asked...

Comment: `s2` can be combination of two string as well.your code will definitely fail when  there is a combination of words.you cant store them in a `list/collection` of separate `String`.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians That's an assumption based on information we don't really have, while it stands true, I had assumed a single "word" match was required

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians The question would then become, are we matching the pattern or just the individual words?  If we are matching the individual words (entered by the user), then the basic principle remains the same, except now we add a loop.

Comment: please have a look my answer this is very simple and two line code and will work in each and every condition.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians But you adding functionality that wasn't called for.  Besides, create new `String`s via `substring` and `String` concatenation inside a loop, isn't the greatest solution in the world...

Answer (score 0):

Just create your collection before you check the existence of input. 
Inside `if` print the frequency of input using `Collections.frequency(lst, s2)`
Get rid of the code after `if`/`else`

```
    ...   
    ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

    Collections.addAll(lst, lstarr);

    if(lst.contains(s2)){
        System.out.println("Input word is present and the count of the string "+s2+" is :" + Collections.frequency(lst, s2));
    }
    ...
```

Comment: please make change  `if(s.contains(s2)){` to `if(lst.contains(s2)){`

Answer (score 0):

use following code-

```
java.util.Scanner scn = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input the sentence");
        String s1 = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Input the word or combination-of-words to be searched");
        String s2 = scn.nextLine();

        /*searching the input word */

        int count=0;

        while(s1.contains(s2)){    
            s1=s1.substring(s1.indexOf(s2)+s2.length(), s1.length()-1);
            count++;
        }
        if(count>0){
            System.out.println("String "+s2+" exists, occures "+count +" times.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("String "+s2+" does not exists.");
        }
```